# QCoreApplication event loop and Windows Service Control Handler Function

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, windows-services, event-loop

I need both event loops: one for *Windows service* (or *Linux daemon*) and another for *Qt* event queue `QCoreApplication::exec()` (or `QApplication::exec()` or even `QEventLoop::exec()`).

Can I have both at the same time in single thread? Or should I create a separate thread for one of them? In the latter case how should be arranged interaction process between `QObject`s and "window"/"service" thread?

*Windows service* requires either [*Message only window*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599(v=vs.85).aspx#message_only) along with *window procedure* to receive and process a messages from the *Windows*, or *Service Control Handler Function*. I want to be able to process both kinds of events comes from the *Windows* and *Qt*-specific ones.

Can I use `QEventLoop/QCoreApplication/QApplication::processEvents` to process *Qt* events between events, that comes from a *Windows*? How can it affect service responsiveness and `QTimer` responsiveness?

Comment: Try to use `QCoreApplication::installNativeEventFilter`

Comment: @ramzes2 Thank you for the direction.

Comment: @ramzes2 It is just about event filters. But what is the origin for events I need? How to generate them?

Comment: What type of windows messages do you want to handle? And is your application really is windows service or just windowless process?

Comment: @ramzes2 My application is windows service. I want to mixin service control messages into the Qt message queues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use QtService library. The QtService is useful for developing Windows services and Unix daemons:
https://github.com/qtproject/qt-solutions/tree/master/qtservice

Alternatively, you can realize it yourself like as in QtService library:
https://github.com/qtproject/qt-solutions/blob/master/qtservice/src/qtservice_win.cpp#L556

Answer (score 1):

Qt event loop integrates native notifications/events on all platforms. The `nativeEventFilter` is how you react to native events when you wish to.

Comment: Maybe I just can't understand how `QCoreApplication` would know that it should call RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx. Is it mandatory part during `QCoreApplication` construction whenever I construct it?

Comment: No, calling that is up to you. But because Qt spins a native windows event pump, the service handlers will be processed as usual.